# PostgreSQL, return columns with invoice counts for year

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

2 tables

1. Company
2. Invoices

I want to return the following

```
Company Name  |  invoice_total_2014   | invoice_total_2013
----------------------------------------------------------
Company A     | 2000                  | 1500
Company B     | 1000                  | 1000
```

So basically it is doing some sort of query for the invoice_total columns with a where date between function.

Is this possible in postgreSQL?

Comment: Yes. It should be possible, providing that you know up-front which years you want to total.

Comment: Yes I do, can you provide an example at all?

Comment: invoice (id, company_id, name, created_at, total)
company (id, name)

Comment: What is the data type of `created_at`?  Add the **full schema** to your post.  You're about to start collecting downvotes.

Comment: it's of type timestamp, the full schema is very large so just trying to keep my example simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    name,
    sum(
        total * (extract(year from created_at) = 2014)::integer
    ) as invoice_total_2014,
    sum(
        total * (extract(year from created_at) = 2013)::integer
    ) as invoice_total_2013
from invoice
group by name
```

Casting a boolean to integer results in 0 or 1

or the traditional `case`

```
select
    name,
    sum(
        case extract(year from created_at) when 2014 then total end
    ) as invoice_total_2014,
    sum(
        case extract(year from created_at) when 2013 then total end
    ) as invoice_total_2013
from invoice
group by name
```

Comment: According to OP comment, `invoice` is a table name.  My best guess is that `invoice.total` fields are to be summed up.